# Formatting titles below two images in same row in Indesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, paragraph-styles

I have three images, one next to another, and I need to put image titles below each image.

The problem is that my image titles are long and can't all fit in one line, so I would need to format every title in two lines. I can't put in separate text boxes, as a there is a footnote at the end of each title saying where the image comes from and I need to have all footnotes in the same place in footer area. I do that easily for the first title, but can't figure a way to do it for the other two titles. Decreasing font size is also not an option, because it is already pretty small.

Any advice?

Comment: Don't start with the easy one. Always start with the hard one and the other ones will conform to same style more easily than the other way around.

Comment: Do you REALLY need long titles?

Comment: Don't forget that you can use alignment to help organize your caption details. For example: Align the caption with the left-hand margin and the image source under the caption ending flush to the right-hand margin on the bottom (separate) line.

Comment: Now when you said it, I'm starting to consider it too. Though I'm only editing a conference proceedings, the authors themselves made the titles, I could probably move one part of it to footer space. I will definitely give that a try and see how it works.

Comment: Are you able to add a screenshot of your layout to the question?

Comment: Don't forget the first rule of typography. "Forget all the rules and do what looks best."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two images mentioned in the question and three in the body copy beneath the title. Mentally cross off the right-hand image, caption, and source for a solution to the title version.

[image]

I'll attempt to do both/either one with this nightmare with three different sized square-cut illustrations and three different aspect ratios each with the same quote used as a stand-in for your captions. Under are the (same) sources flush with the right edge of the respective cut. They can be also centred or flush left with the cut.

The worst one is the third cut with the narrow measure. That required a three-line treatment of the caption. The alignment of the source finishes off the grid to give a "finished" look.